# C# + mysql + ubuntu server encoding issue

Tags: 16.04, mysql, c#

While working on project, which requires database (mysql) usage, I faced an interesting issue, touching cyrillic handling.
Firstly, on the stage of developing everything was pretty nice and straightforward (working on win10, xampp with local mysql).

After migrating onto server (ubuntu 16.04) I realized, that in database cyrillic symbols are showing like '???????'.

UTF-8 is set in the database, program shouldn't be the reason of that, cause on the local database everything looks good.

Vesta CP installed everything to me, no config were touched after this

Where to look or how to fix that?

Comment: BTW standard support for 16.04 ends on the 22 nd of this month. No more questions answered here no more security updates or patches. You need to either upgrade of look into ESM. Esm does not include asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

had to add encoding usage argument, while connecting to database

`Character Set=utf8`
[image: c# code part]